# Can I set different values of parameter target between glBindBuffer and glBufferData

Tags: opengl

I read the `OpenGL Programimg Guide (Sixth Edition)`.

1. It said that the parameter `target` of `glBindData` function only can be set with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.
2. But the  parameter `target` of `glBufferData` can be set with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` and `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`.

Why  can the same parameter have the different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It said that the parameter target of glBindData function only can be set with GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

If you meant `glBindBuffer`, then it's wrong. [You can call `glBindBuffer` with any of the targets.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindBuffer)

Are you sure you're reading the book correctly? Did it say that you could only bind to those targets, or has it simply not talked about `GL_PIXEL_PACK/UNPACK_BUFFER` at that point?

Comment: Maybe there are some mistakes in my book. I read a translating version.